# Whats wrong in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Whats wrong with:

```
$pattern = '/9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11}/';
$subject = '971093342689';
```

trying to check in php

```
preg_match($pattern, $subject)
```

receive an error:

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 22
```

Comment: [This](http://regex101.com/) is a great site for testing regex, maybe it will come in hand.

Comment: You first have one ) and then one (. Your ()[parentheses] aren't right

Answer (score 1):

The two parentheses are not closed:

```
$pattern = '/9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11}/';

                                    ^^^^
```

If it is the sign you need, you have to escape it. otherwise you need an open and a closed parentheses in you regexp.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the parentheses aren't closed. My guess is you should just remove them, since they're not followed by a quantifier (*, +, ? or {}), and you don't have a $matches parameter, so you're not interested in capturing groups.

Also, I don't think [0-5[7-9]] does what you think it does: this means: any of the characters 0 to 5, [, 7 to 9 or ]. You probably want [0-57-9], which means: any of the characters 0 to 5 or 7 to 9